# ruby program for orange tree using instance variables

Tags: ruby, methods, instance-variables

I'm using Chris Pine's ruby tutorial: https://pine.fm/LearnToProgram/?Chapter=09

The task is: 
Make an OrangeTree class. It should have a  height method which returns its height, and a  oneYearPasses method, which, when called, ages the tree one year. Each year the tree grows taller (however much you think an orange tree should grow in a year), and after some number of years (again, your call) the tree should die. For the first few years, it should not produce fruit, but after a while it should, and I guess that older trees produce more each year than younger trees... whatever you think makes most sense. And, of course, you should be able to countTheOranges (which returns the number of oranges on the tree), and pickAnOrange (which reduces the @orangeCount by one and returns a string telling you how delicious the orange was, or else it just tells you that there are no more oranges to pick this year). Make sure that any oranges you don't pick one year fall off before the next year.

Here's my program:

```
class OrangeTree

    def initialize
        @tree = "orange tree"
        @age = 0
        @height = 0
        @fruit = 0
        @fruitPicked = 0
        puts "your " + @tree + " is budding"
    end

    def age
        puts "your " + @tree + " is #{@age} years old."
        @age = @age
        oneYearPasses
    end

    def height
        puts "your " + @tree + " is growing taller."
        @height = @height
    end

    def fruit
        puts "your " + @tree + " has #{@fruit} oranges."
        @fruit = @fruit
    end

    def pickOrange
        puts "pick how many oranges?"
        @fruitPicked = @fruitPicked + gets.chomp.to_i
        puts "you picked #{@fruitPicked} oranges."
    end


    def oneYearPasses
        if @age >= 0
            @age = @age + 1
        end

        if @height >= 0 and @height < 20
            @height = @height + 1
        else
            puts "your " + @tree + " is no longer growing taller."
        end

        if @age >= 3
            @fruit = @fruit + (@age * 2)
        end


        if @age >= 3
            @fruitPicked = @fruitPicked + @fruitPicked
            @fruit = @fruit - @fruitPicked
        end
    end
end

orange = OrangeTree.new
orange.age
orange.age
orange.age
orange.age
orange.age
orange.fruit
orange.pickOrange
orange.fruit
```

My question is why my instance variable @fruit isn't deducting the number of @fruitPicked? orange.fruit keeps outputting the number of oranges the tree grows. Thanks.

Comment: After year passes you are doubling fruit_picked, you should be setting it to zero, and your fruit method should return fruit - fruit_picked. A tip, now you've picked up some basic rubies :) , step sideways and have a look at rspec (or other unit testing framework if you prefer) and have a look at TDD, it would have really helped you with this exercise.

Comment: Or you could leaves fruit as it is, and implement count_the oranges, which would be fruit - fruit_picked.

Answer (score 0):

Because @fruit will be deducted when method oneYearPasses is being called.
So if you want to calculate @fruit every time you call @fruitPicked, maybe you should do this.

```
def pickOrange
    puts "pick how many oranges?"
    @fruitPicked = @fruitPicked + gets.chomp.to_i
    puts "you picked #{@fruitPicked} oranges."
    @fruit = @fruit - @fruitPicked
end
```

the output will be:

orange = OrangeTree.new

your orange tree is budding

orange.age

your orange tree is 0 years old.

orange.age

your orange tree is 1 years old.

orange.age

your orange tree is 2 years old.

orange.age

your orange tree is 3 years old.

orange.age

your orange tree is 4 years old.

orange.fruit

your orange tree has 24 oranges.

orange.pickOrange

pick how many oranges?
4

you picked 4 oranges.

orange.fruit

your orange tree has 20 oranges.

Comment: Thanks, I'm very tempted to put the deduction in the pickOrange method, however I really want to be able to put it inside the oneYearPasses method. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: From my point of view, it's not possible if we want to use oneYearPasses to calculate amount. And for the real case, the amount of orange should be deduct right after picking it. Otherwise you have to calculate after another  year